# Pandas - ValueError: The column label is not unique

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df, which I need to aggregate and then sort:

```
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                     --------------  -----  
 0   player_slug                692 non-null    object 
 1   player_id                  692 non-null    int64  
 2   player_nickname            692 non-null    object 
 3   player_team                692 non-null    int64  
 4   player_position            692 non-null    object 
 5   price_cartoletas           692 non-null    float64
 6   score_mean                 692 non-null    float64
 7   score_no_cleansheets_mean  692 non-null    float64
 8   diff_home_away_s           692 non-null    float64
 9   n_games                    692 non-null    int64  
 10  score_mean_home            692 non-null    float64
 11  score_mean_away            692 non-null    float64
 12  shots_x_mean               692 non-null    float64
 13  fouls_mean                 692 non-null    float64
 14  RB_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 15  PE_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 16  A_mean                     692 non-null    float64
 17  I_mean                     692 non-null    float64
 18  FS_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 19  FF_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 20  G_mean                     692 non-null    float64
 21  DD_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 22  DP_mean                    692 non-null    float64
 23  status                     692 non-null    object 
 24  price_diff                 692 non-null    float64
 25  last_points                692 non-null    float64
```

I do this first:

```
df_agg = medias.groupby('player_slug').agg({'price_cartoletas':['mean']})
```

and it gives me:

```
DF_TEMP                price_cartoletas
                           mean
player_slug                    
abner-felipe               5.09
abner-vinicius             5.28
adalberto                  1.72
adilson                    8.75
adriano                    9.44
...                         ...
yuri                       1.99
yuri-lima                  2.04
ze-marcos                  1.64
ze-rafael                 10.35
zeca                       7.31
```

but when I try to sort it:

```
df_agg.sort_values('price_cartoletas', ascending=False)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: The column label 'price_cartoletas' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

---

How do I sort this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove `[]`, this will create the multiple index on columns

```
df_agg = medias.groupby('player_slug').agg({'price_cartoletas':'mean'}).sort_values('price_cartoletas', ascending=False)
```

Also if you would like multiple index , we can fix from `sort_values`

```
df_agg = df_agg.sort_values(('price_cartoletas','mean'), ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple Columns in the data frame that have the same name you want to merge on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.